# Generate coefficient array from general formula of linear equation system

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, coefficients, finite-difference-method

This is a problem coming out in the implementation of finite difference method (FDM).

Here is a toy example. Suppose we want to solve the boundary value problem (BVP)

$$y''(x)=\sin(x),\ y(0)=0,\ y(1)=0$$

```
eq = y''[x] == Sin[x];
bc = {y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0};
```

with FDM, then we can program as follows. First, write down the corresponding difference formula:

```
Clear@dx;
generalformula = (y[x + dx] - 2 y[x] + y[x - dx])/dx^2 == Sin[x];
```

Then define the grid size and generate difference equations at every grid point:

```
points = 25; domain = {0, 1};
dx = Subtract @@ domain/(1 - points);
var = Table[y[x], {x, ##, dx}] & @@ domain;
differenceeq = Table[generalformula, {x, domain[[1]] + dx, domain[[-1]] - dx, dx}]~Join~bc;
```

Finally solve the difference equations with e.g. `NSolve`:

```
solrule = NSolve[differenceeq, var][[1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00462427, Null} *)
```

BTW, a comparision with the analytic solution:

```
asol = DSolveValue[{eq, bc}, y, x]
Plot[asol[x], {x, ##}, PlotRange -> All]~Show~
   ListPlot[solrule[[All, -1]], DataRange -> {##}] & @@ domain
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can extract the coefficient array from `differenceeq` and solve it with `LinearSolve`, as illustrated in the document of `CoefficientArrays`. This approach is faster than the one using `NSolve`:

```
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[differenceeq, var]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000614324, Null} *)
sol = LinearSolve[marray // N, -barray]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000488251, Null} *)
```

However, this isn't the end. As already mentioned, we've generated difference equation **at every grid point** and then **extract** the coefficient array from the symbolic system in the code above. This procedure can be rather memory-demanding and slow when `points` is large. Is it possible to generate `barray` and `marray` directly from `generalformula` and `bc` **programatically**, in a memory-conserving and not-that-slow way?

---

If the toy example above is too simple to illustrate the underlying problem, the following is a more complicated one attempting to solve the problem mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200366/1871):

```
r = .8; glass = (1.45)^2; air = 1.; k = (2 π)/1.55;
n2 = Function[{x, y}, #] &@If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air];
ClearAll[fw, bw, delta]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw};

fw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{Δ = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + Δ}, {x -> x}})/Δ]
bw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{Δ = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> x - Δ}})/Δ]

delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0
grad = Function[expr, fw@D[expr, #] & /@ {x, y}];
div = Function[expr, Total@MapThread[bw@D@## &, {expr, {x, y}}]];
elst = e[#][x, y] & /@ Range[2];
discretelhs = 
  With[{n2 = n2[x, y]}, 
   div@grad@elst + (n2 k^2) elst - grad[div@elst - 1/n2 div[n2 elst]]] // FullSimplify;
points = 100; L = 2; domain = {-L, L}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
delta["x"] = delta["y"] = -Subtract @@ domain/(points - 1);
vare = Outer[e[#][#2, #3] &, Range@2, del@grid, del@grid, 1] // Flatten;
discretelhslst = 
   Flatten@Transpose[
     Table[discretelhs, {x, del@grid}, {y, del@grid}], {2, 3, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{barray2, marray2} = CoefficientArrays[discretelhslst, vare]; // AbsoluteTiming
{val, vec} = 
   Eigensystem[marray2, -6, 
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2 glass}]; // AbsoluteTiming
mat = ArrayReshape[#, {2, points - 2, points - 2}] & /@ vec;
MapThread[ArrayPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> Sqrt@#2, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &, {mat, val}]
```

[image]

```
ByteCount[marray2]/1024^2. "MB"
(* 1.60567 "MB" *)

ByteCount[discretelhslst]/1024^2. "MB"
(* 44.9877 "MB" *)
```

The corresponding problem is, how to arrive at `marray2` from `discretelhs` without generating `discretelhslst`, in an efficient enough way?

Comment: Would a pre-processed form that is only really applicable for FDM-type matrices be acceptable? I can think up a good way to do that.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm only interested FDM here. What do you mean by "pre-processed form"? If it means something like standard form, I think a requirement is, it should not be too hard to transform a difference formula to that standard form.

Comment: I mean that I take what you supply as this FDM expression and extract the weights from it. Then I can make the FDM matrix easily using sparse methods.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sounds like a proper answer for my question.

Comment: One question about your example problem. It seems as if you have coupled equations in `e[1]` and `e[2]`, so for which of these are we trying to get the difference matrix... I am not much of a DEs aficionado so I'm not sure what the "standard" way to treat that coupling in the FD formulation is.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Both of them, of course. Their arrangement is defined by `vare`.

Comment: I see. My sense is that there is no simple way to wholly automate that kind of arrangement, but there are definitely ways to make building something like that cleaner.

Comment: @xzczd Technical note: if you put `n2 = Function[{x, y}, If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air]]`, then time is reduced by 2 times ;)

Comment: @Alex Surprising. I know `UnitStep` probably won't help (because there's no vectorization), but never expected it actually slows down the code in this case! Code improved. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @xzczd Next tip. Remove `//N` (this is not necessary, since the parameters are not exactly defined) and replace `Block` with `Module`.

Comment: @Alex Again, it's surprising that removing `//N` improves the performance. Actually I add it to handle `grid` because in certain cases complicated symbolic grid can slow down the code, but I didn't expect inexact grid is more complicated in this case. Edited, thx for pointing out. However, `Block` should not be replaced by `Module`, or the Dirichlet b.c. won't be set. Just try `expr = f[4]; Module[{f}, f[x_] =x^2; expr]`. The code still produces reasonable result because b.c. isn't that important for this problem. Another example is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163486/1871

Comment: @xzczd I added a numerical solution to illustrate how your code works compared to code b3m2a1.

Comment: @Alex "The code still produces reasonable result because b.c. isn't that important for this problem. " I have to retract my words… Today I noticed `e[i_][L | -L, _] = e[i_][_, L | -L] = 0.;` is just unnecessary, because the zero Dirichlet b.c. has already been set by `del@grid` in `vare`. (Since the elements at the boundary isn't included in `vare`, `CoefficientArray` will treat these elements as constants and move them to `bmrray2`. This is equivalent to setting zero Dirichlet b.c.. )

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for pointing me to this post. I lost it once and can't remember how it could be found.  So, are you thinking about this code one year?

Comment: @Alex Oh I'm not that persevering :) . I just noticed this when solving [this eigenvalue problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149488/1871) yesterday.

Answer (score 11):

#### Partial ND

It's possible to again extract all this weight data and stuff in the higher dimensional cases using effectively the same procedure as for the 1D:

```
fdmWeightDataND~SetAttributes~HoldAll;
fdmWeightDataND[a_, dep_Symbol, indeps : {__Symbol}, hs : {__Symbol}] :=

  Block[{dep}, Block[indeps, Block[hs,
     Module[{weights, order, denomWeight, denom, num, powed, pows, minpow, 
       pts, x}, denom = Denominator[a];
      (*assumes the mesh spacing is in there at different powers*)

      order = Exponent[denom, #] & /@ hs;
      (*pull the power on the mesh spacing*)

      denomWeight = If[order > 0, Coefficient[denom, hs^order], denom];
      num = Numerator[a];
      {powed, pows} =
       Reap[
        num /.
         dep[args___]?(Not@*FreeQ[Alternatives @@ indeps]) :>
          dep @@
           Sow[
            MapThread[
             Coefficient[#, #2] &,
             {
              {args},
              hs
              }
             ]
            ]
        ];
      minpow = Min[pows];
      weights =
       AssociationThread[
        pows[[1]],
        Map[Coefficient[powed /. (dep @@ #) -> x, x] &, pows[[1]]]
        ];
      <|
       "Weights" -> weights,
       "Orders" -> order
       |>
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

This is less automate-able, though, since you need to specify what your `f`, independent variables, and mesh spacings are. Also without knowing how you'd like to flatten your nD tensor of grid points it's impossible to automatically build the FD matrix. But at a minimum I can give you weights and indices for the weights:

```
(*didn't want to Wikipedia the nine-point stencil so most of this is fake*)

simpleFormula = (
    f[x - xh, y] + f[x + xh, y] +
     f[x, y - yh] + f[x, y + yh] - 4 f[x, y] +
     1/2 f[x + xh, y - yh] + 1/2 f[x - xh, y - yh] +
     1/2 f[x + xh, y + yh] + 1/2 f[x - xh, y + yh]
    )/(xh^2*yh^2);

weights2D = fdmWeightDataND[simpleFormula, f, {x, y}, {xh, yh}]

<|"Weights" -> <|{0, 0} -> -4, {0, -1} -> 1, {0, 1} -> 1, {-1, 0} -> 
    1, {-1, -1} -> 1/2, {-1, 1} -> 1/2, {1, 0} -> 1, {1, -1} -> 1/2, {1, 1} ->
     1/2|>, "Orders" -> {2, 2}|>
```

Basically now you'd pick how to order your grid points and build a matrix from that. Here's one way to do this based on having the second index be the slowest moving (note that I'm only like 50% confident I built this correctly):

```
FDM2D[weightData_, {hx_, hy_}, {nptsx_, nptsy_}] :=

 Module[{xps, yps, weights = weightData["Weights"], 
   orders = weightData["Orders"]},
  xps = Length@DeleteDuplicates@Keys[weights][[All, 1]];
  yps = Length@Sort@DeleteDuplicates@ Keys[weights][[All, 2]];
  SparseArray[
    Flatten@
     KeyValueMap[
      With[{ix = #[[1]], iy = #[[2]], v = #2},
        Map[
         Band[
            If[ix >= 0, {1, 1 + ix}, {1 - ix, 1}] + {#, #} +
             If[iy >= 0, {0, iy*nptsx}, {-iy*nptsx, 0}],
            {nptsx*nptsy, nptsx*nptsx},
            {nptsx, nptsx}
            ] -> v &,
         Range[nptsx - Abs[ix]] - 1
         ]
        ] &,
      weights
      ],
    {nptsx*nptsy, nptsx*nptsx}
    ]/(Times @@ ({hx, hy}^orders))
  ]
```

Here's what that outputs:

```
FDM2D[weights2D, {1, 1}, {5, 5}] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

In the case of no coupling across degrees of freedom this looks correct I believe... (but can't be sure since I usually do my Laplacian via a Kronecker sum):

```
laplacian = (
    f[x - xh, y] + f[x + xh, y] +
     f[x, y - yh] + f[x, y + yh] - 4 f[x, y]
    )/(xh^2*yh^2);

FDM2D[fdmWeightDataND[laplacian, f, {x, y}, {xh, yh}], {1, 1}, {10, 
   10}] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

#### Full Thing for 1D

Here's a method that automates this extraction for 1D FDM stuff:

```
fdmWeightData~SetAttributes~HoldAll;
fdmWeightData[Equal[a_, b_], dep : {__Symbol}, indep : {__Symbol}] := 
  fdmWeightData[a, dep, indep];
fdmWeightData[a_, dep_Symbol, indep_Symbol, h_Symbol] :=

  Block[{dep, indep, h},
   Module[{weights, order, 
     denomWeight, denom,
      num, powed, pows,
     minpow, pts
     },
    denom = Denominator[a];
    (* assumes the mesh spacing is in there *)

    order = Exponent[denom, h];
    (* pull the power on the mesh spacing *)

    denomWeight = Coefficient[ denom, h^order];
    num = Numerator[a];
    {powed, pows} =
     Reap[
      num /.
       dep[expr_?(Not@*FreeQ[indep])] :>
        dep[Sow@Coefficient[expr, h]]
      ];
    minpow = Min[pows];
    powed = powed /. dep[n_] :> dep^(n - minpow);
    weights = (CoefficientList[powed, dep])/denomWeight;
    pts = Exponent[powed, dep, List] + minpow;
    <|
     "Weights" -> weights,
     "Points" -> pts,
     "Order" -> order
     |>
    ]
   ];
fdmWeightData[Equal[expr_, b_]] :=
  fdmWeightData[expr];
fdmWeightData[expr_] :=
  Module[
   {
    vars = Variables[expr],
    dep,
    indep,
    h
    },
   h = FirstCase[vars, _Symbol];
   {dep, indep} =
    Replace[
     FirstCase[vars, a_Symbol[b_Symbol] :> {a, b}, None],
     None :>
      a_Symbol[e_] :> FirstCase[e, Except[h, _Symbol], None, Infinity]
     ] ;
   With[
    {dep = dep, indep = indep, h = h},
    fdmWeightData[expr, dep, indep, h]
    ]
   ];

fdmWeightData[(y[x + dx] - 2 y[x] + y[x - dx])/dx^2 == Sin[x]]

<|"Weights" -> {1, -2, 1}, "Points" -> {-1, 0, 1}, "Order" -> 2|>
```

Here's a helper on that:

```
fdmMat[weights_List, pts_List, order_List, h_, n_] :=
  SparseArray[
   MapThread[
    If[# >= 0,
      Band[{1, # + 1}] -> #2,
      Band[{-# + 1, 1}] -> #2
      ] &,
    {pts, weights/(h^order)}
    ],
   {n, n}
   ];
fdmMat[a_Association, h_, n_] :=

  fdmMat[Sequence @@ Lookup[a, {"Weights", "Points", "Order"}], h, n];
fdmMat[a_Association _, n_] :=
  fdmMat[a, 1, n];
FDMMatrix[a_Association][n_, h_: 1] :=
  fdmMat[a, h, n];
FDMMatrix[expr : Except[_Pattern | _Association]] :=

 FDMMatrix[fdmWeightData[expr]]
FDMMatrix[expr_, dep_, indep_, h_] :=

 FDMMatrix[fdmWeightData[expr, dep, indep, h]]

fdmat = FDMMatrix[(y[x + dx] - 2 y[x] + y[x - dx])/dx^2]

FDMMatrix[<|"Weights" -> {1, -2, 1}, "Points" -> {-1, 0, 1}, "Order" -> 2|>]
```

Then we can make the matrix fast:

```
fdmat[100] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Doing the nD extension will take a bit of thought, though.

#### Partial Solution to Actual Problem

I'm not sure how your actual problem works, but here's a way we can try to build an FD matrix for it using this stuff. The main thing we'll do is break it down into portions with the same `dx` and `dy` terms after doing some symbolic pre-simplification. Here's my new setup (same as yours but entirely symbolic):

```
Clear[r, glass, air, k]
n2 = (Function[{x, y}, #] &@(Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
      PiecewiseExpand@If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air]));
ClearAll[fw, bw, delta]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw};

fw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + \[CapitalDelta]}, {x -> x}})/\[CapitalDelta]]
bw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> x - \[CapitalDelta]}})/\[CapitalDelta]]

delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0
grad = Function[expr, fw@D[expr, #] & /@ {x, y}];
div = Function[expr, Total@MapThread[bw@D@## &, {expr, {x, y}}]];
elst = e[#][x, y] & /@ Range[2];
baseDiscreteLHS =
  With[{n2 = n2[x, y]}, 
   div@grad@elst + (n2 k^2) elst - grad[div@elst - 1/n2 div[n2 elst]]];
```

Now I'll prep this stuff so it's in a form my code can use cleanly:

```
prepped =
  (baseDiscreteLHS[[1]]) //. {
     e[1] -> e1,
     e[2] -> e2,
     delta["y"] -> dy,
     delta["x"] -> dx,
     UnitStep[r^2 - x^2 - y^2] -> usxy,
     UnitStep[r^2 - x^2 - (-dy + y)^2] -> usxdy,
     UnitStep[r^2 - (dx + x)^2 - y^2] -> usdxy,
     UnitStep[r^2 - (dx + x)^2 - (-dy + y)^2] -> usdxdy,
     UnitStep[r^2 - (-dx + x)^2 - y^2] -> usdxmdy
     } // FullSimplify;
```

Now I'll use this stuff to pull the FD weights just for `e1` from the first of the two equations provided:

```
weightsE1 =
  {
   fdmWeightDataND[prepped[[1]], e1, {x, y}, {dx, dy}],
   fdmWeightDataND[prepped[[2]], e1, {x, y}, {dx, dy}],
   fdmWeightDataND[prepped[[3]], e1, {x, y}, {dx, dy}],
   fdmWeightDataND[prepped[[4]], e1, {x, y}, {dx, dy}],
   fdmWeightDataND[
    Simplify[Collect[prepped[[6]] // Expand, dx][[1]]], 
    e1, 
    {x, y}, 
    {dx, dy}
    ],
   fdmWeightDataND[
    Simplify[Collect[prepped[[8]] // Expand, dx][[1]]], 
    e1,
    {x, y}, 
    {dx, dy}
    ]
   };
```

Then I'll build all the matrices, add them together, and numericize everything:

```
mate1 =
 Block[
  {
   r = .8, glass = (1.45)^2, air = 1., k = (2 \[Pi])/1.55,
   sp1, spRules, points = 25,
   dx, dy
   },
  dx = 1./points; dy = 1/points;
  sp1 = FDM2D[#, {dx, dy}, {points, points}] & /@ weightsE1 // Total;
  spRules =
   MapThread[
    # ->
      With[{x = #[[1]]*dx, y = #[[2]]*dy},
       #2 /.
        {
         usxy -> UnitStep[r^2 - x^2 - y^2],
         usxdy -> UnitStep[r^2 - x^2 - (-dy + y)^2],
         usdxy -> UnitStep[r^2 - (dx + x)^2 - y^2],
         usdxdy -> UnitStep[r^2 - (dx + x)^2 - (-dy + y)^2],
         usdxmdy -> UnitStep[r^2 - (-dx + x)^2 - y^2]
         }
       ] &,
    {
     sp1["NonzeroPositions"],
     sp1["NonzeroValues"]
     }
    ];
  SparseArray[spRules, Dimensions[sp1]]
  ]
```

Finally we can solve this using your same `Eigensystem` code:

```
Block[{r = .8, glass = (1.45)^2, air = 1., k = (2 \[Pi])/1.55, points = 25},
  {val, vec} =
   Eigensystem[mate1, -6, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2 glass}
    ];
  mat = ArrayReshape[#, {2, points - 2, points - 2}] & /@ vec;
  MapThread[
   ArrayPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> Sqrt@#2, PlotRange -> All, 
     ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &,
   {mat, val}
   ]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The results are meaningless since I just randomly took part of the problem, but this entire procedure was fast and not memory intensive at all.

Comment: Well, I should say the method is a bit too limited if it can only handle 1D case. Actually the memory issue mainly comes up in high dimensional cases.

Comment: @xzczd my sense is the 1D case can be generalized out if you use a similar preprocessing approach to get the nD forms or if you can reduce the nD case to a tensor product of 1D cases with it. That’ll take work I didn’t have time for though.

Comment: @xzczd I partially handled the nD case

Comment: This code when `points = 100` works 10 times longer than the code by @xzczd. And there is no result. What is the benefit here?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I didn’t bother to actually solve the problem... just showed a way you can decompose his set of equations in this form. Basically you can use the helper functions to do this thing entirely numerically using sparse methods. You’ll still need to use your brain but it can definitely get you there faster if you think about it.

Comment: I’m answering the question “how can you get the weight data from the equations”. The only slow step is having to deal with `UnitStep` which forces stuff to be symbolic. You can handle that separately I believe.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sorry to bother you, but you posted a wrong solution to the problem. I'm trying to find an error in your code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I can think of a few places. Either I'm mis-building the sparse FDM matrix in 2D or I'm missing parts of xczd's equations. I also don't handle the boundary conditions in any way and I'd need to be smarter about that. I think if you want to use this to build the actual FDM matrix you'd also want to be cleverer about how to handle the `UnitStep` stuff.

Comment: (+51) [千金市骨](http://chineselegend.blogspot.com/2008/12/buy-carcass-with-thousand-taels-of.html) :)

Comment: @xzczd sorry I couldn't be more helpful. I'm sure the actual solution to the problem is possible via this weight extraction and matrix construction approach. I just don't have the time right now to actually work on it :| I'd love to come back to this someday though when I am back to programming mostly in Mathematica. As I see it, all I'm trying to do here is automate what every standard text on the FDM has you do (construct blog diagonal matrices based on some simple recurrence) but things where there is more complex grid dependence still require care.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I corrected typos and added a numerical solution to illustrate how your code works.

Answer (score 3):

To compare code @xzczd and @b3m2a1, I took a simplified version of the 2D operator from the topic [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199563/how-to-set-interface-conditions-for-optical-waveguide-in-ndeigensystem/200366#200366) and 300x300 cells. I simplified code @xzczd  a little, so it works 3 times faster. Code  @b3m2a1, on the contrary, I complicated a little, so that it works 30 times faster. As a result, they now work equally fast and produce the same output.

Code @xzczd

```
r = .8; glass = (1.45)^2; air = 1.; k = (2 \[Pi])/1.55;
n2[x_, y_] := If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air];
ClearAll[fw, bw, delta]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw};

fw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + \[CapitalDelta]}, {x -> 
         x}})/\[CapitalDelta]]
bw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> 
         x - \[CapitalDelta]}})/\[CapitalDelta]]

delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0
grad = Function[expr, fw@D[expr, #] & /@ {x, y}];
div = Function[expr, Total@MapThread[bw@D@## &, {expr, {x, y}}]];
elst = e[#][x, y] & /@ Range[1];
discretelhs = 
  With[{n2 = n2[x, y]}, div@grad@elst + (k^2*n2 ) elst] // 
   FullSimplify;
points = 302; L = 2; domain = {-L, L}; grid = 
 Array[# &, points, domain];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
delta["x"] = delta["y"] = -Subtract @@ domain/(points - 1);
vare = Outer[e[#][#2, #3] &, Range@1, del@grid, del@grid, 1] // 
   Flatten;
discretelhslst = 
   Flatten@Transpose[
     Module[{e}, e[i_][L | -L, _] = e[i_][_, L | -L] = 0.;
      Table[discretelhs, {x, del@grid}, {y, del@grid}]], {2, 3, 
      1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{barray2, marray2} = 
   CoefficientArrays[discretelhslst, vare]; // AbsoluteTiming
{val, vec} = 
   Eigensystem[marray2, -4, 
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2 glass}]; // AbsoluteTiming
mat = ArrayReshape[#, {2, points - 2, points - 2}] & /@ vec;
MapThread[
 ArrayPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> Sqrt@#2, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &, {mat, val}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Code  @b3m2a1

```
fdmWeightDataND~SetAttributes~HoldAll;
fdmWeightDataND[a_, dep_Symbol, indeps : {__Symbol}, 
   hs : {__Symbol}] := 
  Block[{dep}, 
   Block[indeps, 
    Block[hs, 
     Module[{weights, order, denomWeight, denom, num, powed, pows, 
       minpow, pts, x}, denom = Denominator[a];
      (*assumes the mesh spacing is in there at different powers*)
      order = Exponent[denom, #] & /@ hs;
      (*pull the power on the mesh spacing*)
      denomWeight = If[order > 0, Coefficient[denom, hs^order], denom];
      num = Numerator[a];
      {powed, pows} = 
       Reap[num /. 
         dep[args___]?(Not@*FreeQ[Alternatives @@ indeps]) :> 
          dep @@ Sow[MapThread[Coefficient[#, #2] &, {{args}, hs}]]];
      minpow = Min[pows];
      weights = 
       AssociationThread[pows[[1]], 
        Map[Coefficient[powed /. (dep @@ #) -> x, x] &, pows[[1]]]];
      <|"Weights" -> weights, "Orders" -> order|>]]]];


FDM2D[weightData_, {hx_, hy_}, {nptsx_, nptsy_}] := 
 Module[{xps, yps, weights = weightData["Weights"], 
   orders = weightData["Orders"]}, 
  xps = Length@DeleteDuplicates@Keys[weights][[All, 1]];
  yps = Length@Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Keys[weights][[All, 2]];
  SparseArray[
    Flatten@KeyValueMap[
      With[{ix = #[[1]], iy = #[[2]], v = #2}, 
        Map[Band[
            If[ix >= 0, {1, 1 + ix}, {1 - ix, 1}] + {#, #} + 
             If[iy >= 0, {0, iy*nptsx}, {-iy*nptsx, 0}], {nptsx*nptsy,
              nptsx*nptsx}, {nptsx, nptsx}] -> v &, 
         Range[nptsx - Abs[ix]] - 1]] &, weights], {nptsx*nptsy, 
     nptsx*nptsx}]/(Times @@ ({hx, hy}^orders))]


ClearAll[fw, bw, delta]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw};

fw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + \[CapitalDelta]}, {x -> 
         x}})/\[CapitalDelta]]
bw@D[expr_, x_] := 
 With[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta@ToString@x}, 
  Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> 
         x - \[CapitalDelta]}})/\[CapitalDelta]]

delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0
grad = Function[expr, fw@D[expr, #] & /@ {x, y}];
div = Function[expr, Total@MapThread[bw@D@## &, {expr, {x, y}}]];
elst = e[#][x, y] & /@ Range[1];
baseDiscreteLHS = Together[div@grad@elst];
prepped = (baseDiscreteLHS[[1]]) //. {e[1] -> e1, delta["y"] -> dy, 
    delta["x"] -> dx};
weightsE1 = {fdmWeightDataND[prepped, e1, {x, y}, {dx, dy}]};
mate1 = Block[{sp1, spRules, points = 300, dx, dy}, 
    dx = 4./(points + 1); dy = 4./(points + 1);
    sp1 = FDM2D[#, {dx, dy}, {points, points}] & /@ weightsE1 // Total;
    spRules = 
     MapThread[# -> With[{x = #[[1]]*dx, y = #[[2]]*dy}, #2] &, {sp1[
        "NonzeroPositions"], sp1["NonzeroValues"]}];
    SparseArray[spRules, Dimensions[sp1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
r = .8; glass = (1.45)^2; air = 1.; k = (2 \[Pi])/1.55;
n2[x_, y_] := If[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, glass, air]; discretelhs = 
 With[{n2 = n2[x, y]}, (k^2*n2) elst];
points1 = 302; L = 2; domain = {-L, L}; grid = 
 Array[# &, points1, domain];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
delta["x"] = delta["y"] = -Subtract @@ domain/(points1 - 1);
vare = Outer[e[#][#2, #3] &, Range@1, del@grid, del@grid, 1] // 
   Flatten;
discretelhslst = 
  Flatten@Transpose[
    Module[{e}, e[i_][L | -L, _] = e[i_][_, L | -L] = 0.;
     Table[discretelhs, {x, del@grid}, {y, del@grid}]], {2, 3, 1}];
{barray2, marray2} = 
   CoefficientArrays[discretelhslst, vare]; // AbsoluteTiming
points = 300; {val, vec} = 
  Eigensystem[mate1 + marray2, -4, 
   Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2*glass}]; // AbsoluteTiming
mat = ArrayReshape[#, {2, points, points}] & /@ vec;
MapThread[
 ArrayPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> Sqrt[#2], PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &, {mat, val}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Finally, compare with my method that I suggested for this problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199563/how-to-set-interface-conditions-for-optical-waveguide-in-ndeigensystem/200366#200366) using FEM:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
r = 0.8; ne = 4;
reg = ImplicitRegion[-2 <= x <= 2 && -2 <= y <= 2, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.0004 (1 + 9 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]];


glass = 1.45; air = 1.; k0 = (2 \[Pi])/1.55; b = I*Sqrt[glass]*k0*1.37;
n[R_] := If[R <= r, glass^2, air^2]*k0^2

helm = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - (b^2 + n[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]])*
    u[x, y];
boundary = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];

{vals, funs} = 
     NDEigensystem[{helm, boundary}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    ne]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[DensityPlot[Im[funs[[i]]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Im[Sqrt[vals[[i]] + b^2]], Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicks -> None], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comparing the data in Figure 1-3, we find that there is an eigenvalue match in methods FDM and FEM. The small difference can be explained by the difference in the number of cells.

Comment: Very nice! What did you have to patch in my code, if you don't mind my asking? I should integrate the changes and quash whatever bugs you found.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I used your code to calculate the laplacian matrix. I used a different code to calculate the diagonal matrix, since your code hangs on a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add my incomplete answer. I call it incomplete because a general-purposed function hasn't been created (yet), but I do find a general strategy for handling the problem.

The idea is simple: generate coefficient array of general difference formula with `CoefficientArray` first, then generate the complete array using the general coefficients.

I'll solve the 2D problem in the question for illustration. `delta`, `discretelhs` etc. are the same as in the question.

```
sfx = Rescale[#, {x, x + delta@"x"}, {nx, nx + 1}] &;
sfy = Rescale[#, {y, y + delta@"y"}, {ny, ny + 1}] &;
rule = e[i_][x_, y_] :> {i, sfx@x // Simplify, sfy@y // Simplify};
varegeneral = Union@Cases[discretelhs, e[_][__], Infinity];
index = {i, nx, ny, ##} & @@@ (varegeneral /. rule);
coelst = Last@CoefficientArrays[discretelhs, varegeneral];
marrayfast = 
   Flatten[SparseArray[
      Flatten[#, 
          3] &@(Unevaluated@
            Compile[{}, 
             Table[term, {i, 2}, {nx, 2, pts - 1}, {ny, 2, pts - 1}]] /. {term -> index, 
            pts -> points})[] -> (Flatten[#, 
           3] &@(Unevaluated@
             Compile[{}, Table[lst[[i]], {i, 2}, {x, dgrid}, {y, dgrid}]] /. {dgrid -> 
              del@grid, 
             lst -> (Normal@coelst /. {HoldPattern@glass -> glass, 
                 HoldPattern@air -> air})})[]), {2, points, points, 2, points, 
       points}][[All, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2, All, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]], {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
      6}}]; // AbsoluteTiming

MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2. MB

marrayfast == marray2
(* True *)

{val, vec} = 
   Eigensystem[marrayfast, -6, 
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> k^2 glass}]; // AbsoluteTiming

MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2. MB

mat = ArrayReshape[#, {2, points - 2, points - 2}] & /@ vec;
MapThread[ArrayPlot[#[[1]], PlotLabel -> Sqrt@#2, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &, {mat, val}]
```

When `points = 500`, it only takes `5.63068` seconds to generate `marrayfast`, while `53.4027 + 19.1697` to generate `marray2`.

Memory usage is also reduced, but the real bottleneck seems to be `Eigensystem`, so perhaps it's not a big deal.

Comment: My guess is you can generalize out your `marrayfast` using some type of `KroneckerProduct`. Unless that is where you are also choosing to deal with that pesky `UnitStep` term.